# play framework send file in HTTP request

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a play framework 2 application and I would like to call a WebService and send a file ( an image ). I found the WS class but I cannot find how to send a file using it.
What I found is this :

```
WS.url("http://localhost:9001/post").post("content")
```

But I did not managed to send a file using a POST request.

Can someone  tell me how to do it ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Play > 2.0 this should do the trick:

```
File file = new File("yourPath");
WS.url("/post/url").post(file);
```

Being able to add a parameter identifying your file the request should be send using multipart/form-data.
This Post shows how to do it with Play! - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18723326/2788883

Comment: Thanks but how do I specify the name of my parameter like: monfile=the_file_I_send inside the body ?

Comment: In that case you might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18723326/2788883

Answer (score 0):

use following method to return response as file

```
RenderBinary(java.io.File file, java.lang.String name)
```

To see API follow this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/api/play/mvc/results/RenderBinary.html#RenderBinary(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)).